# How to plot arrows from angles of wind direction using vectors

Tags: gnuplot

I hope someone can help me. I'm trying to plot the angle of wind and colour the strength of the wind. The colour palette for wind strength is fine, but I'm having trouble converting the angle to a vector and plotting the arrow correctly - ideally with no 'tail'/ line..
This is a sample of the data file:

```
"Date", "Temp", "icon", "rain", "snow", "wind.speed", "wind.deg", "clouds.all"
"2019-12-29 18:00:00",5.58,"04n",,,"n",2.45,185,51,1025
"2019-12-29 21:00:00",5.36,"04n",,,"n",2.51,182,99,1025
"2019-12-30 00:00:00",5.34,"04n",,,"n",2.6,196,95,1025
"2019-12-30 03:00:00",5.28,"03n",,,"n",2.72,207,47,1024
"2019-12-30 06:00:00",5.23,"02n",,,"n",2.62,200,23,1024
"2019-12-30 09:00:00",5.47,"01d",,,"d",2.48,214,0,1024
"2019-12-30 12:00:00",9.82,"01d",,,"d",3.96,215,0,1023
"2019-12-30 15:00:00",8.94,"01d",,,"d",3.24,218,0,1021
"2019-12-30 18:00:00",6.18,"01n",,,"n",2.88,214,0,1022
"2019-12-30 21:00:00",5.75,"01n",,,"n",2.13,232,0,1022
"2019-12-31 00:00:00",5.82,"03n",,,"n",0.8,216,33,1022
"2019-12-31 03:00:00",5.18,"04n",,,"n",0.32,8,66,1022
"2019-12-31 06:00:00",5.37,"04n",,,"n",1.79,58,83,1022
"2019-12-31 09:00:00",5.1,"04d",,,"d",3.88,66,100,1023
"2019-12-31 12:00:00",7.97,"04d",,,"d",4.39,84,100,1025
"2019-12-31 15:00:00",8.52,"04d",,,"d",3.97,74,100,1025
"2019-12-31 18:00:00",7.83,"04n",,,"n",2.97,58,100,1026
"2019-12-31 21:00:00",7.93,"04n",,,"n",4.08,72,100,1027
```

This is the code I have so far - mostly from here: http://www.gnuplotting.org/vector-field-from-data-file/

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset

set datafile missing "?"
set datafile separator ","

set terminal pngcairo true transparent truecolor size 1800, 500
set output '~/meteogram/vector.png'

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

set palette defined ( 0 '#ffffff', \
1 '#ffee00',\
2 '#ff7000',\
3 '#ee0000',\
4 '#7f0000')

xf(phi) = 10*cos(phi/180.0*pi+pi/2)
yf(phi) = 10*sin(phi/180.0*pi+pi/2)

plot FILE every 1 using 1:($7-yf($8)):(2*xf($8)):(2*yf($8)):7 with vectors head fixed filled lc palette
```

I'm trying to get a plot something like this image from a website
[image]
So just an arrow rotated to indicate the direction of the wind (coloured by strength) but plotted at the same y-value
And I should add that I'm using Gnuplot 5.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, not a gnuplot expert, but other software I have used understood the idea of a "zero length" tail. Maybe there is such a thing here? Also would be good if you could illustrate your required output VS current output. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 set datafile missing "?"
 set datafile separator ","
 set xdata time
 set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
 set ang deg
 unset key
 unset colorbox

 plot 'wind.dat' using 1:7:("➤"):8:7 with labels rotate variable textcolor palette
```

This example uses the unicode glyph U+27A4 "BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD".   Other possible characters: →

The precise appearance depends on the font and the font size.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @ethan - that's excellent. I was wondering about labels but didn't think it would work. I'm very grateful for your prompt and accurate reply!

Comment: Just to complete this for anyone else interested. The wind direction is given as an angle from 0° so I used a unicode glyph pointing down "⮟" and reversed the direction of the rotation - using `1:7:("⮟"):(0-$8):7`